# Simple proof of $\ln x \leq x-1$

Tags: functions, proof-verification, logarithms

Is this simple proof for $\ln x \leq x-1$ valid?

Proof:

Since $\ln$ is concave, let $y, x \in \mathbb{R}_{++}.$ We have that $\ln(y) \leq \ln(x) + \frac{d\ln x}{dx}(y-x)$. Since this is valid $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}_{++}$, it must be valid for an arbitrary $y$ and $x=1$. Then, we get that $\ln(y) \leq \frac{1}{x}(y-x) \Rightarrow \ln(y) \leq y-1$.

Thanks

Comment: Consider using \ln to get $\ln$ instead of $ln$

Comment: @FlybyNight Better yet, use  $\log$ instead of $\ln$.

Comment: What is you definition of $\log(x)$?  For a proof that uses pre-calculus tools only, see [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263).

Comment: @MarkViola There seems to be a UK/US/Applied/Pure divide on this. My experience of UK applied Maths is that $\log$ is often used to denote the base-10 logarithm $\log_{10}$, while $\ln$ is used for the natural logarithm $\ln x \equiv \log_{\mathrm e} x$. (I believe $\ln$ comes from the Latin *logarithmus naturalis*). Having said that, I've seen $\log$ used for $\log_{\mathrm e}$ a lot in analytic number theory books, even from British authors.

Comment: Log(x) can be seen as the natural logarithm. Thanks for the pre-calculos @MarkViola but I was just asking if this proof is right.

Comment: @jpugliese Sorry, I hope it is not a stupid question, but from concavity how do you obtain that $\ln(y) \leq \ln(x) + \frac{d\ln x}{dx}(y-x)$?

Comment: $\Bbb{R}_{++}$ isn't standard notation. Do you mean $\Bbb{R}_{>0}$?

Comment: @jpugliese Sorry but I can't give an opinion about your proof if you don't explain the first step, I can't really understand where it come from.

Comment: @gimusi From the extended MVT, we have $\log(x)=\log(1)+\frac{1}{1}(x-1)+\frac12 \left(-\frac{1}{\xi^2}\right)(x-1)^2$ for some $\xi\in (\min(1,x), \max(1,x))$.  The concavity argument simply tells us the sign of the second order term already (it's negative).  And this yields the coveted inequality.

Comment: @MarkViola Ah ok of course! Thanks a lot. Then all works fine!

Comment: @jpugliese Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thanks @gimusi. I'm going to do that. The first part of what I wrote follows because, if $f$ is concave and diff, then $f(z) \geq (1-t)f(x) + tf(y)$, where $z = (1-t)x + ty$. We can rewrite z as $z = x + t(y-x)$. Then, $f(x + t(y-x)) - f(x) \geq t(f(y)-f(x))$. Dividing both sides by t, and applying the limit as t tends to zero, we get that the LHS of the above equation will be the $\bigtriangledown f(x) \cdot (y-x)$, i.e., the diretional derivative of $f(x)$ in the direction of the vector $(y-x)$. The result then follows:  $\bigtriangledown f(x) \cdot (y-x) \geq f(y) - f(x)$. I applied to ln.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simply way is to consider $f(x)=x-\ln x -1$ for $x>0$ and note that

- $f'(x)=1-\frac1x=0 \implies x=1 \quad f(1)=0$
- $f''(x)=\frac1{x^2}>0$ then $f(1)$ is a minimum

Comment: Thanks gimusi. My friend just did this proof and was wondering if it was right. Without meaning to be rude, this is a proof-verification post; is the proof I presented correct?

Comment: @jpugliese You are right! I check

Answer (score 3):

The proof given in the OP is acceptable given $(i)$ $\log(1)=0$, $(ii)$ $\frac{d\log(x)}{dx}=\frac1x$ and $(iii)$ the logarithm is concave.

Another way forward it to note that since your tacit definition of $\log(x)$ is $\log(x)=\int_1^x \frac1t\,dt$, $x>0$, then we have from elementary analysis of the integral

$$\frac{x-1}{x}=\int_1^x \frac1x \,dt\le \log(x)\le \int_1^x \frac11\,dt=x-1$$

Comment: Thanks Mark. My friend just did this proof and was wondering if it was right. Without meaning to be rude, this is a proof-verification post; is the proof I presented correct?

Comment: You're welcome.  The proof looks fine given that $\log(1)=0$, $\frac{d\log(x)}{dx}=\frac1x$, and the logarithm function is concave.